# Why does a missing primary key/unique key cause deadlock issues on upsert?

Tags: sql, database, postgresql, concurrency, relational-database

I came across a schema and an upsert stored procedure that was causing deadlock issues. I have a general idea about why this is causing deadlock and how to fix it. I can reproduce it but I don't have a clear understanding of the sequence of steps that is causing it. It would be great if someone can explain clearly why this is causing deadlock.

Here is the schema and the stored procedures. This code is being executed on PostgreSQL 9.2.2.

```
CREATE TABLE counters (                                                                                                                                                                                                                       
  count_type INTEGER NOT NULL,
  count_id   INTEGER NOT NULL,
  count      INTEGER NOT NULL
);


CREATE TABLE primary_relation (
  id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,
  a_counter INTEGER NOT NULL DEFAULT 0
);

INSERT INTO primary_relation
SELECT i FROM generate_series(1,5) AS i;

CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION increment_count(ctype integer, cid integer, i integer) RETURNS VOID
AS $$
BEGIN
    LOOP
        UPDATE counters
         SET count = count + i 
         WHERE count_type = ctype AND count_id = cid;
         IF FOUND THEN
            RETURN;
          END IF; 
        BEGIN
            INSERT INTO counters (count_type, count_id, count)
             VALUES (ctype, cid, i); 
            RETURN;
        EXCEPTION WHEN OTHERS THEN
        END;
    END LOOP;
END;
$$
LANGUAGE PLPGSQL;

CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION update_primary_a_count(ctype integer) RETURNS VOID
AS $$
  WITH deleted_counts_cte AS (
      DELETE
      FROM counters
      WHERE count_type = ctype
      RETURNING *
  ), rollup_cte AS (
      SELECT count_id, SUM(count) AS count
      FROM deleted_counts_cte
      GROUP BY count_id
      HAVING SUM(count) <> 0
  )
  UPDATE primary_relation
  SET a_counter = a_counter + rollup_cte.count
  FROM rollup_cte
  WHERE primary_relation.id = rollup_cte.count_id
$$ LANGUAGE SQL;
```

And here is a python script to reproduce the deadlock.

```
import os                                                                                                                                                                                                                                     
import random
import time
import psycopg2

COUNTERS = 5 
THREADS = 10
ITERATIONS = 500 

def increment():
  outf = open('synctest.out.%d' % os.getpid(), 'w')
  conn = psycopg2.connect(database="test")
  cur = conn.cursor()
  for i in range(0,ITERATIONS):
    time.sleep(random.random())
    start = time.time()
    cur.execute("SELECT increment_count(0, %s, 1)", [random.randint(1,COUNTERS)])
    conn.commit()
    outf.write("%f\n" % (time.time() - start))
  conn.close()
  outf.close()

def update(n):
  outf = open('synctest.update', 'w')
  conn = psycopg2.connect(database="test")
  cur = conn.cursor()
  for i in range(0,n):
    time.sleep(random.random())
    start = time.time()
    cur.execute("SELECT update_primary_a_count(0)")
    conn.commit()
    outf.write("%f\n" % (time.time() - start))
  conn.close()

pids = []
for i in range(THREADS):
  pid = os.fork()
  if pid != 0:
    print 'Process %d spawned' % pid 
    pids.append(pid)
  else:
    print 'Starting child %d' % os.getpid()
    increment()
    print 'Exiting child %d' % os.getpid()
    os._exit(0)

update(ITERATIONS)
for pid in pids:
  print "waiting on %d" % pid 
  os.waitpid(pid, 0)

# cleanup
update(1)
```

I recognize that one issue with this is that the upsert will can produce duplicate rows (with multiple writers) which will likely result in some double counting. But why will this result in deadlock?

The error I get from PostgreSQL is something like the following:

```
process 91924 detected deadlock while waiting for ShareLock on transaction 4683083 after 100.559 ms",,,,,"SQL statement ""UPDATE counters
```

And the client spews something like this:

```
psycopg2.extensions.TransactionRollbackError: deadlock detected
DETAIL:  Process 91924 waits for ShareLock on transaction 4683083; blocked by process 91933.
Process 91933 waits for ShareLock on transaction 4683079; blocked by process 91924.
HINT:  See server log for query details.CONTEXT:  SQL statement "UPDATE counters
         SET count = count + i
         WHERE count_type = ctype AND count_id = cid"
PL/pgSQL function increment_count(integer,integer,integer) line 4 at SQL statement
```

To fix the issue, you need to add a primary key like so:

```
ALTER TABLE counters ADD PRIMARY KEY (count_type, count_id);
```

Any insight would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: what is upsert? I don't see it in your code nor do I know this non-english word..

Comment: @Tomas upsert is a general term for "update or insert". I apologize. It may be jargon in the documentation for some but not all RDMS or the SQL standards. The `increment_count` function above is a fairly typical "upsert" stored procedure in PostgreSQL. See the `merge_db()` block here http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.2/static/plpgsql-control-structures.html for the example of "upsert" from the PG docs.

Comment: Why is there a LOOP in increment_count? Not that it would have anything to do with the issue.

Comment: @Jayadevan: with a PK, you could have two threads failing the update and concurrently trying the insert, with one failing. The loop allows to try the update again. (My best guess is this why it's deadlocking without the PK, too, but I'm unsure why…)

Comment: Here is a great discussion on why upsert is difficult http://www.depesz.com/2012/06/10/why-is-upsert-so-complicated/.

Comment: This provides some kind of an answer? http://postgresql.1045698.n5.nabble.com/how-to-avoid-deadlock-on-masive-update-with-multiples-delete-td5726622.html

Comment: Without a unique key, the database must take a lock on a page for the update.  You're running 500 iterations of 10 threads.  As soon as the table is large enough to span multiple pages and the update needs multiples, there arises the possibility of two particular updates needing two pages at the "same time" but locking them in reverse order - deadlock.  The table and the function must change for the degree of concurrency you want.  The primary key is critical but may not be sufficient if you increase threads to 2000 and iterations to 10k.

Comment: @AndrewWolfe: I think you should post that as an answer instead.

Comment: @AndrewWolfe sounds like you are on to something. Is this something that could be induced manually and repeated? For example, is there a way to force a table to span multiple pages to test your theory? Also, can you elaborate on your comment that "the table and the function must change for the degree of concurrency you want"?

Answer (score 1):

because of the primary key, the number of rows in this table is always <= # threads, and the primary key ensures that no row is repeated.

When you remove the primary key, some of the threads get lagged behind and the number of rows increases, and at the same time rows get repeated. When the rows get repeated, then the update time is longer and 2 or more threads will try to update the same row(s).

Open a new terminal and type:

```
watch --interval 1 "psql -tc \"select count(*) from counters\" test"
```

Try this with and without the primary key. When you get the first deadlock, look at the results of the query above. In my case this is what I am left with in the table counters:

```
test=# select * from counters order by 2;
 count_type | count_id | count 
------------+----------+-------
          0 |        1 |   735
          0 |        1 |   733
          0 |        1 |   735
          0 |        1 |   735
          0 |        2 |   916
          0 |        2 |   914
          0 |        2 |   914
          0 |        3 |   882
          0 |        4 |   999
          0 |        5 |   691
          0 |        5 |   692
(11 rows)
```

Comment: your answer states facts about the problem but doesn't explain why the deadlock occurs. We know that it occurs. What is missing is a precise explanation and a sequence of steps that will result in a deadlock that is easily reproducible.

Comment: My apologies, the deadlocks occur because of many reasons.
`1. Number of updated
2. Number of deletes
3. Autovacuum/vacuum
4. Postgres MVCC (multi version concurrency control)
`
Every update or delete, postgres does not actually delete that row, it "copies" it to the end of the table disabling the row that got updated/deleted. The vacuum flags those row as to be-reused.

The more updates/deletes the bigger the table gets, the longer autovacuum will take, slowing down a tiny bit each transaction.

Comment: And the tables size never decreases, so the more row you update/delete the bigger the table will get. Its not difficult to recreate this problem, disable autovacuum, and after a few minutes you will see the table will be several MB in size, even though there will be no rows, and any operation on that table will take longer and longer.

Answer (score 1):

Your code is the perfect recipe for a race condition (multiple threads, random sleeps).
The problem is most probably due to locking issues, since you don't mention the locking mode i'm going to assume that is a page based lock so, you get the following scenario:

1. Thread 1 starts, it begins to insert records, lets say that it locks page n° 1, and should lock page 2.
2. Thread 2 starts, at the same time as 1, but it locks first page 2, and should lock page 1 next.
3. Both threads are now waiting on each other to complete, so you have a deadlock.

Now, why a PK fixes it?

Because locking is done via index at first, you the race condition is mitigated because the PK is unique on the inserts, so all threads wait for the index, and in updates access is done via index so the record is locked based on its PK.

Answer (score 0):

At some point one user is waiting on a lock another user has, while the first user owns a lock that the second user wants. This is what causes a deadlock.

At a guess, it's because without a primary key (or in fact any key) when you UPDATE counters in your increment sp it is having to read the whole table. The same with the primary_relation table. This is going to leave locks strewn about, and open the way for a deadlock. I'm not a Postgres user so I don't know the details of exactly when it will place locks, but I'm pretty sure that this is what is happening.

Putting a PK on counters is making it possible for the DB to target the rows it reads accurately and put on the minimum number of locks. You should really have a PK on primary_relation too!

Comment: This doesn't answer the question. OP is wondering *why* this particular set of functions deadlocks, not what a deadlock is (which he knows) or how to avoid one (which he found already). And there is a PK on primary_relation already.